# Как прочитать файл через JS на сервере

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, сервер

Всем привет!Мне нужно прочитать файл допустим us_quantity.txt и поместить значение файла допустим в переменную us_quantity,я гуглил,честное слово но наткнулся на то,что js не может получить доступ к файлам на сервере т.к. это не серверный язык в отличии например от php,можно можно ли это как-то реализовать не на чистом js,а с наример какими-то библиотеками...?Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Да, "чего-то не понимаете". Что есть "значение файла"?

Comment: значение-то что в нем написано?ну цифры,а именно 35

Comment: если файл доступен по http(s), то вы можете его прочитать на стороне клиента.

Comment: а как?можешь устроить простым и понятным скриптом?

Comment: по братски)) смотрите на nodejs

Comment: а без него?....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью JavaScript можно обратиться к файлу на сервере, используя объект `XMLHttpRequest`, например, следующим образом:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

request.open('GET', 'us_quantity.txt', true);

request.onload = function () {
    console.log(request.responseText);
};

request.send(null);
```

Comment: @andreymal, а где об этом сказано? Как я понял, нужно именно прочитать файл: «Мне нужно прочитать файл допустим us_quantity.txt и поместить значение файла допустим в переменную us_quantity»

Comment: Оу, я криво прочитал, прошу прощения

Comment: Большое спасибо!